# Ultrasonic Sensor Serial Output Grounding Issue

Tags: digital-logic, sensor, circuit-design, logic-level

I have a small circuit which uses a Maxbotix Ultrasonic sensor (Datasheet: https://www.maxbotix.com/documents/HRLV-MaxSonar-EZ_Datasheet.pdf) to take distance measurements and then transmit them over bluetooth with a BLE Nano 2 IC. The circuit is powered by 3 AA batteries. My problem is that the circuit only works when I physically touch the circuit thereby providing (I assume) additional grounding. To be specific, this sensor outputs TTL Serial data; the data is garbage unless I am touching the circuit.

I am a novice when it comes to circuit design. Can anyone please advise how I might go about solving this problem?

[image: Circuit Diagram]

**Updated Schematic**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2202g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: When you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar the editable image gets saved inline with the post. No need for screengrabs, uploads and background grid. The advantage is that we can copy and edit in improvements in our answers.

Comment: Looking at a datasheet for the NRF52832, I see a max recommended supply voltage of 3.6V (Man Rev 1, Page 17).  Also, powering a device from a DIO line is considered bad form, as the expected output voltage is 0.7xVdd.  By powering the 1043 from a dio pin, and then using another dio for communication (farther reducing voltage), you're asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first reaction:

Try a high side switch to toggle the power to the 1043 instead of the current MOSFET configuration.  This will preserve your ground reference for the serial communication.

Or, for a quick test, hard-wire the 1043 to be 'On' all the time and see if the problem goes away.

You can hard-wire the 1043 to be always 'On' by:

- Removing the MOSFET1
- Connect the GND terminal of the MB1043 to the negative terminal of your batteries.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmTqUr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I removed the MOSFET completely and changed the GPIO-D5 pin to high instead of low, connecting the 1043 to ground directly. I have a couple of these circuits built and one of them actually works perfectly now, however the others still require me to touch them. They seem to be just on the edge. Is there anything else I might try?

Comment: Add a new updated schematic, as your comment about D5 is not clear.

Comment: Updated schematic added

Comment: Does the above diagram work?  Change the power supply to 3V (2 x 1.5V batteries), and try again.  Once the above works as expected, then look into https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/blogs/introduction-to-high-side-load-switches (for example) to turn the MB1043 on/off from the NRF52832.

Comment: Update: So switching to 3v power seemed to make a difference. My circuit was working in testing and we got 4 units deployed for further testing in the field. However, they were running over the weekend, taking a readings every 15 minutes, and as of this morning were only able to intermittently get good data. I do intend to eventually update the circuit to use a high-side switch as per your suggestion, but wanted to first test as-is. Would the high-side switch likely do anything to help with this grounding issue, or is there something else we might try for that particular problem?

Comment: What was the battery voltage at the end of the weekend?

Comment: What do you mean by tested as-as?  Which schematic, the one i made, or the one you have shown?